# function with no finite limit

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that there exists no real valued function with infinite limit at every point. I can do it using Baire's theorem for example, but I need help with doing it in more elementary way.

Comment: At least one of the sets $A_n=\{ x\in[0,1]\mid |f(x)|<n\}$ is infinite, by considering cardinalities.